# Cancel local requests on component destroy

Tags: angularjs

Consider you have some component e.g. autocomplete that sends GET request to server:

```
...
someObject = create();
vm.search = someFactory.getHttp(params).then(result => {
  someObjet.prop = result;
});

vm.$onDestroy = () => {
  someObject = null;
}
```

If component is destroyed while request is pending, callback will throw js error.
I know that in this concrete example I can solve this using simple If, however quite obvious that it is better to canel this request:

```
var canceler = $q.defer();
vm.search = someFactory.getHttp(params, canceler)...

vm.$onDestroy = () => {
      canceler.resolve();
      someObject = null;
}
```

This works perfectly, but having such code in each component seems weird. I would like to have something like:

```
vm.search = someFactory.getHttp(params, $scope.destroyPromise)
```

But such thing does not seem to exist...

Question: Is there any easy way to cancel requests on component destroy?
both in Angularjs or in Angular

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've done in Angular is use RXjs for requests, using subscriptions, and adding those subscriptions to an array that we iterate over and cancel on destroy, like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute }              from "@angular/router";

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscriptions = [];

    constructor(private route AppRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscriptions.push(this.route.data.subscribe());
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        for (let subscription of this.subscriptions) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign the created object to an object that doesn't get destroyed? This way your behaviour is maintained and the you can do a simple check to prevent any errors.

```
...
var baseObj = {};
baseObj.someObject = create();
vm.search = someFactory.getHttp(params).then(result => {
    if (baseObj.someObject != null) {
        baseObj.someObjet.prop = result;
    }
});

vm.$onDestroy = () => {
  baseObj.someObject = null;
}
```

Comment: I gave very-very simple example. E.g. callback may also call some statefull factory methods (and yes statefull factories are bad, but sometimes it saves tons of code lines) -- so I do not want to think about "How write callback, so it wont throw errrors" -- I want this callback be never executed one component is destroyed.